# how to set width and height to arrays elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

i'm trying to set width and height to elements in array in java script, for example i have 3 main element in array:"Home","Download","Support" which i call them box, each  box should be 600*400 and all picture in home array should be set in this box and that is for all of them, each box in html code is col-lg-3, here is my code, I appreciate if anybody help me.

JavaScript code:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    var Title = [{ title: "Metro UI template" },
                 { title: "Build Windows 8 style websites, with ease" }]
    $("#dvTitle").append("<div class='col-lg-9'><a href = '#'><h1>" + Title[0].title + "</h1><h4>" + Title[1].title + "</h4></div> ");

    var Menu = [
       { title: "Home", image: '../Icons/1.png' },
       { title: "Download", image: '../Icons/2.png' },
       { title: "Support", image: '../Icons/3.png' }
    ]
    for (i = 0; i < Menu.length; i++) {
        $("#dvTitleMenu").append("<div class='col-lg-3'><a href='#'> <h3 > " + Menu[i].title + "</h3><img src=" + Menu[i].image + "  style='width:30px; height:30px;'/> </a></div> ");
    }
    var aMenu =[ 
       { title: "Home",
           items: [{  image: '../Images/1-1.PNG' },
                   {  image: '../Images/1-2.PNG' },
                   {  image: '../Images/1-3.PNG' },
                   {  image: '../Images/1-4.PNG' },
                   {  image: '../Images/1-5.PNG' }] } ,

       { title: "Download",
           items: [{ image: "/Images/2-1.PNG" },
                   { image: "/Images/2-2.PNG" },
                   { image: "/Images/2-3.PNG" },
                   { image: "/Images/2-4.PNG" }] } ,

      {
          title: "Support",
          items: [{image: "/Images/3-1.PNG" },
                 { image: "/Images/3-2.PNG" },
                 { image: "/Images/3-3.PNG" },
                 { image: "/Images/3-4.PNG" }]
      }
                   ]

    for (i = 0; i < aMenu.length; i++) {

        $("#dvcontent").append("<div class='col-lg-12'><a href='#'> <h3> " + aMenu[i].title + "</h3> </a></div> ");

        for (var j = 0; j < aMenu[i].items.length; j++) {

            $("#dvcontent").append("<a href='#'><img src=" + aMenu[i].items[j].image + " /> </a> ");
        }
    }
});
```

HTML code:

```
<body id="body">
    <div id="dvMain">
        <div id="dvHeader" class="row">
            <div id="dvTitle" class="col-lg-8">
            </div>
            <div id="dvTitleMenu" class="col-lg-4">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="dvcontent" >
            <div id="dvHome" class="col-lg-3">
            </div>

            <div id="dvDownload" class="col-lg-3">
            </div>

            <div id="dvSupport" class="col-lg-3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```